# Is there any way to add a single component to multiple component groups in AEM [Adobe Experience Manager]

Tags: aem, aem-6

I need to add a single component to multiple component groups in AEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that a component can only belong to one component group.
If you would like to have your component visible in different places (but not the complete group), you basically have two options:

1. Add the component (not the group) to the allowed components list in your design ( configuration.
2. Create a new group, change your component's group to the newly created one and add the new group in the design / configs you need.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking about the 2nd way.. curiously wanted to know is there any way to do that or not. I am a newbie in AEM